# How to use grids in modal bootstrap dialogs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use the `bootstrap-5` grid system inside a `modal` popup.
For testing, I simply took the main modal example from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/, and added the grid example inside the `modal-body`:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">.col-md-4 .ms-auto</div>
    </div>
  ....
```

Result: the grid is not respected in any way. But why?

https://jsfiddle.net/3041fLwk/

Comment: "the grid is not respected in any way". I'm not seeing this in your fiddle. The grid works as expected.

Comment: Not for me, see comments below please.

Comment: What is the viewport screen width you're testing with? Do you have a screenshot that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is bootstrap doesn't implement responsive on modal.
It relies on parent window for `media` queries.
The same if you create a smallbox with limited width.

To implement responsive on modal is to use `iframe`, or gotta set breakpoint on modal yourself

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is coming from your use of `ms-auto` - when I removed all of the `ms-auto` classes the grid worked as expected.

Comment: Could you give a modified working example? I remove all `ms-auto` classes, but the grid still not working: https://jsfiddle.net/o9pgse5v/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle you sent works fine. Remember that there are a total of 12 columns in a row. I've added some background colors and added more `.col-md`s to make it easier to see the grid: https://cdn.mrsandywilly.com/screenshots/sHfD9uGB0h.png Any `col-md` will fill the remaining space available. https://jsfiddle.net/wjp9t05v/

Comment: No, it is not! Look at the example (that I just copied) from the bootstrap homepage: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#using-the-grid > Launch demo modal. As you can see, there are not just straight lines all over the width. They are distributed, at that's exactly what's not working inside the modal example.